Is there a notation for normed spaces $(X, \| \cdot \|_X)$ and $(Y, \| \cdot \|_Y )$ such that $X = Y$ and $\| x \|_X = \| x \|_Y$ for all $x \in X$?
Suppose that we are dealing with two abstract nomed spaces $(X, \| \cdot \|_X )$ and $(Y, \| \cdot \|_Y)$ such that $ X = Y $ (that is, every element of $X$ belongs to $Y$ and every element of $Y$ belongs to $X$). Furthermore, assume that
$$ \| x \|_X = \| x \|_Y \qquad \qquad \forall x \in X. $$
My question is pretty simple: is there a typical notation to represent this relation of the two normed spaces ? That is, is there an usual notation to represent two normed spaces that are equal and have equal norms for every element?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Would the downvoter care to elaborate ?

$(X,|\cdot|_X)=(Y,|\cdot|_Y)$.

This is sort of an awkward concept. The condition that $X = Y$ on the nose violates the principle of equivalence; it will almost never be the case that two sets are exactly equal on the nose, and in any case the question of whether two sets are exactly equal on the nose is sensitive to "implementation details" of exactly how those sets are constructed (e.g. whether you construct $\mathbb{R}$ using Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences) which should not in any reasonable sense matter. Also you haven't said anything about whether the vector space structures on $X$ and $Y$ agree or not, which I assume you meant to.
The better condition to ask for, which respects the principle of equivalence, is to ask that a given map $f : X \to Y$ is a linear bijection satisfying $\| x \|_X = \| f(x) \|_Y$. When this happens $f$ is called an isometric isomorphism. Famous important examples include the various Fourier transforms.
If you really want to insist that $X = Y$ on the nose I would just call them identical; in that case why even have separate notation for them? Then you're just talking about two norms on a single vector space which coincide (there's no issue with talking about equality here).

Thanks for your kind answer. Perhaps I should give more details about the framework I am working on. I am working with classical function spaces and studying relations between them. It is quite common to find function spaces that generalise other function spaces, and it is usual to deal with function spaces that coincide, in the sense that every function that belongs to one space also belongs to the other one. Now, under certain scenarios, one can work with normed function spaces where this happens. So, it is interesting to know if besides the set equality there is also a norm equality, (...)

(...) which is what I tried to describe on my post. In resume, one can think of function spaces as just sets of elements, and the equality in this sense means just that every function that belongs to one space also belongs to the other. However, I believe that it is also interesting to wonder about the norm equality, and was wondering if there was a specific notation in the literature for this.

@xyz: I would just write $(X, | - |_X) = (Y, | - |_Y)$ for this, I guess, with the understanding that $X$ and $Y$ are subspaces of some larger function space. Are there interesting examples where the norms coincide and this is not obvious from the definitions?

Thanks for your comment. I agree with your notation. I believe  that I will stick with it if I can't come up with a better idea. As for your question, you can lookup the Morrey Spaces $L^{p,\lambda}(\Omega)$, which coincide with $L^p(\Omega)$, when $\lambda = 0$. I wouldn't say it is hard to see from the definitions, but I also wouldn't say it is obvious. There might be better examples but this is the one that came to my mind!
